# Skylanders Swap Force, are wii and wii u versions the same?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-u, skylanders-swap-force

For Skylanders Swap Force, are the Wii and Wii U versions the same?

I know the Wii version can be played on the Wii U, but will we be missing out on the new Wii U features, or is it the same release in different packaging?

I've looked through the reviews and haven't found any relevant info...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying both versions on the wii u, I can definitely say that it is not the same release in different packaging.

The ***graphics suffer tremendously*** when playing the wii version on the wii u, the game play is similar enough, but it is really worth getting the wii u version if you can.

Comment: Wait, did you answer your own question?

Comment: @peper757 , Yes, I answered my own question... Like I said in my answer, the graphics suffer a lot when playing the wii version on the wii u... It looked a little like the old N64 games.

Answer (score 0):

All the figures can be used on different platforms interchangeably. I should think there would be involvement with the gamepad, but otherwise:

It's "the same release in different packaging".

See: http://www.officialnintendomagazine.co.uk/51729/skylanders-swap-force-wii-will-be-very-close-to-the-hd-versions/

Comment: Do you have a source or reference that suggests that its the same, or are you just assuming that its the same?

Comment: @apaul34208 Source added.

Comment: I tested it myself, the two versions are not the same.

Comment: @apaul34208 What are the differences?